# I am getting running out of memory when I am running my program. is there a better way to do it or am I creating any infinite loops?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to create this code to decipher things in Caesar. I know my spelling is really bad but this project was just for fun and I don't know much about programming yet.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",]
var input = prompt("Enter In The Text That You Want To Decode")
var results = []

//Decoding
var ceaser_alphabet = []

var cAlphabet_creation_progress = 1

var ceaser_progress = 1
var decoding_progress = 1

var decoded_message = ""

var slice1 = []
var slice2 = []

var decoder = function () {
//Uses 25 instead of 26 because the first item in an array is counted as "0"
    slice1 = alphabet.slice(0, (26 - ceaser_progress))
    slice2 = alphabet.slice((26 - ceaser_progress), 26)

    while (cAlphabet_creation_progress < 26) {
        if (cAlphabet_creation_progress < slice1.length) {
            ceaser_alphabet.push(slice1[cAlphabet_creation_progress])
        } else {
            ceaser_alphabet.push(slice2[cAlphabet_creation_progress])
        }
    }

//Decoding
    while(decoding_progress < input.length) {
        if (!input.charAt(decoding_progress) == " ") {
            decoded_message = decoded_message + ceaser_alphabet[ceaser_alphabet.indexOf(alphabet.indexOf(input.charAt(decoding_progress)))]
            decoding_progress++
        } else {
            decoded_message = decoded_message + " "
        }
    }

    if (decoding_progress == input.length) {
        results.push(decoded_message)
        ceaser_progress++
        decoding_progress = 1
        ceaser_alphabet = []
        decoded_message = ""
    }
}
var possibilities_left = 26
while (possibilities_left > 0) {
    possibilities_left-- 
    decoder()
}
console.log(results)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it on chrome it says that it runs out of memory. Another problem might also be that you are just not suppose to do this thing on chrome.

Comment: Out of memory usually indicates an infinite loop. Check the conditions on all your loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is your first `while` statement is looping indefinitely as the variable `cAlphabet_creation_progress` is not being incremented

```
while (cAlphabet_creation_progress < 26) {
    if (cAlphabet_creation_progress < slice1.length) {
        ceaser_alphabet.push(slice1[cAlphabet_creation_progress])
    } else {
        ceaser_alphabet.push(slice2[cAlphabet_creation_progress])
    }
    cAlphabet_creation_progress++ //needs to be incremented
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I feel so dumb now

Comment: No problem, never feel dumb just less informed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this wasn't your original question, but I think you'll have a problem with your decoder class. Unless I'm misreading your code, the conditional if statement:

```
    if (!input.charAt(decoding_progress) == " ") {
```

Should be:

```
    if (input.charAt(decoding_progress) != " ")
```

If you're trying to check if it isn't a space.

Comment: i believe you are correct here as well.  ! should only be placed in front of Boolean variables to check if false.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLee, I should probably work on being a little more confident in my answers!